# Images in Kivy app not displayed (show black box) after filling up memory, not released

Tags: python, image, touch, kivy, raspberry-pi3

I've been using the Kivy sample Python code to try to make a slideshow on the official Raspberry Pi touchscreen. When I loop through a jpg photo directory, the images eventually refuse to show up, displaying a black box only. I get no error messages. I think it's a memory leak, though I'm not sure how to test this. The following code (which downloads a photo, copies it 9 times and displays each file with a delay of 3 seconds per photo) stops displaying images at #7. If I use larger images, they stop appearing earlier. Shouldn't clearing the widgets free up the memory?

main.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6')
from kivy.clock import Clock
import urllib
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from functools import partial
from kivy.core.window import Window
import shutil    

def displayphoto(i, root, *largs):
    name=str(i)+".jpg"
    root.clear_widgets()
    img = Image(source=name, nocache=False)
    root.add_widget(img)
    label = Label(text=name)
    root.add_widget(label)

class NoscatterApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = FloatLayout()
        #os.remove("*.jpg")
        urllib.urlretrieve("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/68/Shed_with_green_roof_at_Lyngen_fjord%2C_2012_June.jpg/1200px-Shed_with_green_roof_at_Lyngen_fjord%2C_2012_June.jpg", "main.jpg")
        for i in range(0, 10):
            name=str(i)+".jpg"
            shutil.copy("main.jpg", name)        
            Clock.schedule_once(partial(displayphoto, i, root), i*3)    
        return root

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NoscatterApp().run()
```

Comment: Have you observed that same problem on a PC?

Comment: Haven’t tried on PC. I’m guessing it’s a memory leak.... lots of small photos or a few larger photos eventually do this.  I’m simplifying the code and will update

Comment: For me it is a specific problem of raspberry pi and similar cards due to the hardware limitations they have, please try it on a normal PC to download that is caused by hw.

Comment: It would be interesting to see if the above code leaks memory on a PC, if you could test it I would much appreciate it as I don't have easy access to a PC

Comment: You can monitor the consumption of resources using htop in the raspberry.

Comment: @VictorVanHee: Your app ran without problem on a laptop. Have you try replacing ***Image*** with ***AsyncImage***?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but try using `AsyncImage` instead of `Image`

```
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage

img = Image(source=name, nocache=False)
```

If this doesn't fix the issue, try setting `nocache=True`. 
This significantly reduced the amount of times I encountered a black image, but still not fully fixed.

Finally I ended up resizing and compressing the original image using PIL, which completely fixed the issue for me.

```
from PIL import Image as PILImage  # Name conflict with kivy.uix.image

img = Image(nocache=False)
pil_image = PILImage.open(name)
pil_image.thumbnail((512, 512)) # Pick any size you want.

pil_image.save("temp/current_image.jpg", format='JPEG', optimize=True, quality=90)
# Lower quality = more compression

img.source = "temp/current_image.jpg"
```

The original image on disk remains the same and only the one displayed is compressed. Any other technique that reduces the image size should also work.